# Delete text after semicolon

Tags: linux, text

I have a file with columns as shown below

```
chr1    899766  899766  G   T   exonic;exonic   KLHL17  .   nonsynonymous SNV;nonsynonymous SNV
```

I want to delete text after ";" in columns 6 and 9. The output should look like:

```
chr1    899766  899766  G   T   exonic  KLHL17  .   nonsynonymous SNV
```

Could someone give a linux command to solve this.

Comment: It's unclear from your question example what the column separator is. Is it a tab character, or is it two or more spaces or possibly something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will delete the parts including and after `;` in any field, assuming fields are separated by Tabs.

```
sed 's/;[^\t]*//g' <file>
```

If you want to do it only in the 6th and 9th fields:

```
perl -lne '@F=split/\t/;$F[$_]=~s/;.*// for(5,8);print join"\t",@F' <file>
```

Comment: It is a tab delimited file and i want to delete in only specific columns. It should not delete any field with ;.

Comment: Thanks, the perl script works.sed command is not working as expected and the output look like "exonicxonic" and  "nonsynonymous SNVonsynonymous SNV"

Comment: Sorry, just fixed the sed version.

Answer (score 0):

for your desired input, i have used `sed`

```
echo "chr1    899766  899766  G   T   exonic;exonic   KLHL17  .   nonsynonymous SNV;nonsynonymous SNV" | sed 's/;[a-zA-Z]* [a-zA-Z]*//g'
```

output

```
chr1    899766  899766  G   T   exonic  KLHL17  .   nonsynonymous SNV
```

it will only work for "`word;word`" or "`word word;word word`"